# How to find a document by id and update it's set?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and Node.js to talk to the database. I have an Id of the document and I need to update the set of this document. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  taskModel.update({
 _id: ObjectId(taskid), 'results.date': new Date(date) },
{ $set: { 'results.done': true }},
 callback);
```

This is how I'm getting ObjectId method

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

this is what db returns:

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0, lastOp: Timestamp 
{ _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 0, high_: 0 }, electionId: 565e1be0d66545dcd16d55ce }
```

It doesn't update the document.

This is how the document looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5668a45ccc23cef6c375ddd4"),
"userid" : "test",
"title" : "to do groceries",
"source" : "Walmart",
"results" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-12-09T21:56:51.076Z"),
        "done" : false
    }
]
}
```

The date is correct. The issue with ObjectID apparently. Google didn't help. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your Schema `results` is an array but you are accessing `results.date` so replace it with `results[0].date` then it will work.

Comment: The idea is to find element in the array by date. So far there is only one element, but later will be many. [0] doesn't help because it can be any other element. But thanks for attempt.

Comment: You just hinted me! I forgot to use $ positional operator. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I had to use the positional operator $.

```
  taskModel.update({
 _id: ObjectId(taskid), 'results.date': new Date(date) },
{ $set: { 'results.$.done': true }},
 callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Hamabama, you have to use the **positional operator $**. but you should use **multi** option as well for updating all the document.

```
taskModel.update({
 _id: ObjectId(taskid), 'results.date': new Date(date) },
{ $set: { 'results.$.done': true }},
{ multi: true },
 callback);
```

Comment: I should have been more clear that I needed to update one particular document, not many. But thank you.